# mysql query that outputs a table of data showing count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have researched this and have not found the answer, so I thought someone here could shed some light. I'm trying to create a table of data returned showing the number of games picked for each user grouped by week numbers.

### **Database structure:**

```
id  |  user   |   team    | week_number
----+---------+-----------+-------------
1   |  john   |  eagles   |  1 
2   |  john   |  saints   |  1 
3   |  harry  |  patriots |  1 
4   |  frank  |  cowboys  |  1
5   |  john   |  falcons  |  2
6   |  frank  |  cardinals|  2
```

### **Desired output:**

```
week_number | frank | harry | john
------------+-------+-------+-------
     1      |    1  |    1  |   2
     2      |    1  |    0  |   1
```

I'll be using `PHP` to display the output.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to your desired output could be:

```
WEEK_NUMBER USER    GAMES  
1          frank    1  
1          harry    1  
1          john     2  
2          frank    1  
2          john     1
```

If this output could work for you, then you can run the following query:

```
select week_number,user,count(team) as games from table 
group by week_number,user;
```

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head in the wall, I got enlightenment and got the query finally. ;)

You could run this to achieve your desired output:

```
SELECT  T.week_number,
        IFNULL(SUM((CASE WHEN T.user = 'frank' THEN T.games END)),0) frank,
        IFNULL(SUM((CASE WHEN T.user = 'harry' THEN T.games END)),0) harry,
        IFNULL(SUM((CASE WHEN T.user = 'john' THEN T.games END)),0) john
FROM    (select week_number,user,count(team) as games from table_name group by week_number,user) as T
GROUP BY week_number
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2cc3/1/0)